# Does it make any scientific sense that a comet coming to crush Earth would appear "sideways" from a telescope and on the sky (from Earth)?

Tags: physics, earth, telescope, comet, optical

In multiple different movies and fiction, there's the threat of a burning space comet heading for Earth, threatening to kill everyone and destroy the planet.

One example is the animated *Comet in Moominland* (1992).

When they look at it in a telescope, and later it's seen on the sky, it's depicted as a burning ball with a trail, seemingly going sideways, to the right, *past* Earth. If it were heading toward Earth, wouldn't it have no visible "tail", but simply be a big round burning ball which gets increasingly bigger?

Am I fundamentally missing something here? Why do they so often depict it appearing "sideways" rather than "frontways"? Would a comet heading straight to Earth ever appear to be going past Earth, or for some reason have a trail/tail to the left of the big burning sphere, even though it's coming for us?

Comment: This is an interesting question and the details of **actual** comet tail behavior is well covered in Astronomy SE already so if asked there it would probably be quickly closed as duplicate. However a question about **comets in movies** would be in my opinion a great question in Movies SE or Science Fiction and Fantasy SE! Have a look around those sites and see what you think.

Comment: Any video of a ship with smoke stacks chugging along on a windy day?  Or someone walking around with a flag on a windy day?

Comment: This would seem not to be a question of space exploration, but astronomy.

Comment: Opinions of "better suited to Astronomy" **do not make something off-topic here**. There are currently **55 questions tagged with comet** including [22 also including "tail"](https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcomet%5D+tail) the newest of which is [Have spacecraft ever passed through the tails of comets?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48368/12102) Voting to **reopen** because this is not off-topic.

Comment: @uhoh - while questions about comets do exist, they generally relate to space exploration through the interaction between spacecraft and comets, or how a comet might be explored, etc.  This is just a question about the general behavior of comets when viewed from Earth.  It's on the edge, but if you want to give a reason, then it would fall under "heliophysics and planetary science", not "we have some already".

Comment: @IronEagle there have been a few discussions in the last few years on this: [planetary science: overlap with Astronomy SE](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1366/12102) and [Is this question truly off-topic? Or are people just (over) reacting to the “may be better suited” comment?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1306/12102) I think it's fairly certain now that questions like this are not off-topic and that this *has already been settled* and isn't something that we need to do over and over every time somebody adds a "better suited to Astronomy" opinion. We don't close them.

Comment: @IronEagle similar discussion for a slightly different situation [What celestial mechanics questions are on topic here?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1492/12102) and some more on process: [Should we revise thresholds on the celestial mechanics question?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1508/12102)

Comment: @IronEagle sorry for so many comments, but see my first comment: [This is an interesting question and the details of actual comet tail behavior is well covered in Astronomy SE already **so if asked there it would probably be quickly closed as duplicate.**](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48281/?noredirect=1#comment155967_48281) The only effects of closing would be to block further answers and possibly reduce visibility here, and subsequent migration there which may result again in closure as duplicate. Neither are better outcomes than leaving this on-topic question open here.

Comment: SE is good answers to on-topic questions, anything that gets in the way of that most likely should be avoided.

Answer (score 98):

The comet's tail always points away from the Sun. Yes, even when the comet is heading back into the outer solar system.

This is because the tail isn't a 'trail' of where the comet has been, like a rocket exhaust or contrail, but instead it's gas, ice and other debris blown off by the stellar wind.

(There's actually [two tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_tail), one made of charged particles, and one of neutral dust, but that's not especially relevant to the question)

You can see the tail behaviour clearly in the image below.
[image: comet tail always points away from sun image]

So yes, while movies about comets are often [notoriously inaccurate](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/4697/armageddon-in-nasa-training), you can indeed have a comet coming toward earth with a tail pointed sideways. But, I suspect accuracy is not why they depict the comet with a sideways tail in movies. A front-end comet will not be nearly as recognisable to viewers as a sideways one.

Comment: "This is because the tail isn't a 'trail' of where the comet has been, like a rocket exhaust or contrail, but instead it's gas, ice and other debris blown off by the stellar wind." Even if it was, it'd be entirely possible for it to be positioned "sideways" compared to the Earth as it came in for a collision, if its trajectory was perpendicular to the Earth's.

Comment: @nick012000 As Ingolifs has pointed out, the comet's trajectory doesn't matter, only the position relative to earth and sun. If it came from the direction of the sun, the tail could even (nearly) point towards earth.

Comment: “isn't a 'trail' of where the comet has been, like a rocket exhaust” – rocket exhaust also only forms such a trail whilst in the atmosphere. In vacuum, the exhaust tends to disperse in all direction, but even if you avoided that (which would be possible with an extremely large nozzle extension) then it wouldn't point “backwards” in the intuitive sense either. _Away from the rocket's back_, yes, but depending on what maneuver you're performing the rocket could point in any direction, not necessarily along its orbit (though that is usually most efficient).

Comment: @Zac67 Yes, I realise that. My point was that even if that wasn’t true, you could still have a comet moving sideways and hitting the Earth.

Comment: weird. This has now become my highest rated answer on this SE and I almost posted it as a comment. I don't ever think I'll get used to the weird Pareto-law stuff that happens to posts here.

Answer (score 15):

While those movies probably do it because that's how comets are commonly depicted, it might not be that inaccurate. Remember that [the Earth itself is moving around the Sun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_orbit), so if a comet is heading for Earth, that means it's heading for a point where Earth will *eventually* be, not where it currently is. It would therefore be possible to see such a comet be "sideways".

Comment: This is not really the right or at least the complete answer yet. You should begin with "The only wind the comet experiences comes from the Sun" and then describe why comets have two tails sometimes. But it is good that you've pointed out that since both objects *primarily orbit the Sun* their collision trajectories will not have them moving straight at each other.

Comment: @uhoh I'd go a bit further... It's _half_ the answer. The other half is in the answer by Ingolfis.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with it - the trajectory of a comet makes *no difference whatsoever* in where the tail points. Yes, you can see a comet tail side-on from the earth, but whether the comet is heading toward earth, or toward where the earth will, or in any other direction won't change a thing about where the tail points. How a comet's tail looks only depends on where it *is*, not where it's *going*.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I think the point though is that even if the tail points directly behind the comet, that doesn't necessarily mean you won't see it sideways. The question could be construed as "if a comet was on a collision course with Earth, wouldn't its trajectory be directly toward an observer on Earth?" and I would say the answer to that is no.

Comment: The concept of "directly behind" doesn't really make sense in space. All motion is relative.

Comment: @DarthFennec But there's no point in discussing the trajectory, as it doesn't affect the tail in any way. Whether or not the trajectory is pointed directly toward the earth, or toward where the earth will be, makes no difference. Even if the trajectory points directly at the earth, you could *still* see a side-on tail, like if the comet was in the earth's orbit but going the opposite direction. Or, you could have a trajectory pointing directly at the earth with a head-on tail, like if the comet comes from far outside the earth's orbit. The trajectory is irrelevant to the direction of the tail.

Comment: @DarthFennec ... the rephrased question is not at all equivalent to the original one. You're correct that a comet on a collision course with earth will probably not have a trajectory pointed directly at earth. But that gives absolutely no information about the trajectory of the tail. A comet with a trajectory nearly orthogonal to the direction of earth could still have a tail pointed directly at the planet. Or, it could have a tail pointed orthogonally to the direction of earth.

Comment: @bdsl By "directly behind" I of course mean "opposite to the direction of motion". I thought that was obvious from context but sure, I could have been more clear.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I read the question in two parts. One, making the incorrect assumption that the tail is "behind" the comet. Two, making the incorrect assumption that the trajectory of a collision course would be directly toward an observer. Showing that *either* assumption is false is enough to answer the question, but I would argue that you need *both* for a complete answer. So, sure, the question is technically asking about the tail, so focusing on the tail is valid, but I think it ignores the other (more implicit) half of the question.

Comment: @DarthFennec But direction of motion relative to what reference?

Comment: That applies if the comet is several months out, but not if it's only a few days away.

Comment: @Acccumulation Nah, it’d still apply right up until the moment of impact. Consider two cars moving towards a 90 degree intersection where they’ll collide. They’ll maintain a constant angle between them right up until impact.

Comment: @bdsl the Earth

Comment: @nick012000 only assuming they are traveling at the same speed. If one goes faster, the angle varies.

Comment: @Tim At least _on_ Earth, the angle stays the same for two vehicles on a collision course even if their speeds are different.  For example, if a pilot sees an aircraft stay in the same spot on the windscreen, that gets the pilot's immediate attention: https://www.flyingmag.com/technique/tip-week/beware-stationary-objects/ .  But neither the Earth nor the comet are moving in a straight line; I don't know if that changes things.

Answer (score 15):

If you're the comet, the way to hit Earth is not to head directly for it. That's because Earth is orbiting the sun: you need to aim at where Earth *will be*, not where it is right now.

For example:

[image: Animation of InSight trajectory.gif]

By [Phoenix7777](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Phoenix7777) - Own work
Data source: HORIZONS System, JPL, NASA, [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), [Link](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=71080434)

This shows a transfer orbit from Earth (blue) to Mars (green), but the basics of orbital mechanics are the same for a comet. Just imagine the probe (purple) is the comet, on a trajectory to collide with Earth (green).

As you can see, the comet isn't headed "right at" Earth. Rather it's mostly headed in the same direction as Earth, which is a counter-clockwise rotation in this image. If you could somehow see the path the comet is traveling from Earth, it would not be behind the comet, but to the side.

But also, the trail of a comet does not leave debris in its path. Burning/smoking/vaporizing things do this on Earth because as the gas/small particulates/whatever is being blown off by the air as the object flies through Earth's atmosphere. Since the apparent direction of this wind is behind the direction of travel of the object, the trail traces out a path of where the object has been.

But in space there is no atmosphere, and so the "wind" blowing stuff off the comet is not related to the comet's direction of travel. Instead, the wind is always coming from the sun. Consequently, the tail is predominately away from the sun, regardless of which way the comet is traveling.

Comment: What a well-written answer.